# Facebook's iOS SDK logConversionPixel equivalent on Android

Tags: android, facebook

We have an Android application that needs to track installations in Facebook Ads.

On iOS we achieve this by calling the [logConversionPixel:valueOfPixel](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBInsights#logConversionPixel%3AvalueOfPixel%3A) method of the Facebook SDK. But I've been unable to find an equivalent method in the Android one.